# alert(data.status) fails when status=false but not when status=true

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
alert(data.status);
```

`data` is a JSON object, one of its fields is `status` (a Boolean field).

When `JSON.stringify(data)` returns:

`{"result":[{"income":"1000","expense":"2000"}],"errors":{},"status":true}`

the code above does output `true`, but when `JSON.stringify(data)` returns:

`{"result":null,"errors":{"user":"nonexistent user"},"status":false}`

the code above breaks - i.e. it does not alert anything, and the rest of my JavaScript code is not executed as well.

Any idea why, and/or how to fix/bypass it?

Comment: I believe you may have a conflict between "status" property within the result and "status" of the response itself.

Comment: If you are using this alert for debugging purposes, you may be better off using `console.log(status);`

Comment: Impossible to say without some context. A surrounding function perhaps. A testcase that reproduces the issue (the AJAX element can almost certainly be entirely abstracted out of this question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is elsewhere. Try this simple test in Firebug (or some other console):

```
var data = JSON.parse(
        '{"result":null,"errors":{"user":"nonexistent user"},"status":false}')
alert(data.status);
```

It works fine.

Comment: +1: The testcase the OP should have written and used to conclude that _this_ question is without merit, before posting it. In other words, basic debugging. \*yawn\*

Comment: @lwburk You are correct. My error was trying to iterate prior to `alert(data.status);` through `data.result` by `$.each(data.result, function(i, user) {...}`. If `status` was false, it would **ACTUALLY** fail on trying to iterate through null. On this Firebug gave me a message about an error in the jquery.js file. It would have been helpful if I had been alerted on accessing the null reference in MY CODE. If someone knows the correct way to debug such errors and is willing to share - it would be much appreciated!